# dse cassandra analytics and online in same cluster

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise

I have a cluster running datastax cassandra with 8 nodes of which 3 are analytic nodes. When I create a table in analytic nodes, it is created in non analytic nodes as well. How could this be prevented but the tables and table updates from non-analytic nodes should flow into the analytic nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the tables in a keyspace that only specifies replication in the Analytics Datacenter. You can do this by using the NetworkTopology Strategy [(Documentation on NTS)](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/architecture/architectureDataDistributeReplication_c.html). Having the table only exist on specific nodes is only supported if you are putting those nodes in a separate datacenter.